# Is querying time/cycles a serialized or a parallel request for all cores/threads?

Tags: c++, system-clock

Assuming there is a simple "which thread finishes loop first" benchmark,

```
#include<thread>
#include<iostream>
#include<mutex>

int main()
{
    std::mutex m;

    std::thread t1([&](){
        auto c1=clock();
        for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++){ /* some unremovable logic here */  }
        auto c2=clock();

        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g(m);
        std::cout<<"t1:  "<<c2-c1<<"  "<<std::endl;
    });

    std::thread t2([&](){
        auto c1=clock();
        for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++){ /* some unremovable logic here */  }
        auto c2=clock();

        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g(m);
        std::cout<<"t2:  "<<c2-c1<<"  "<<std::endl;
    });


    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

can we trust `clock()` or any other time/clock request function to be not serialized between threads and be always independent so that measuring it won't change the order which thread completes work?

If there is single clock cycle counter for whole CPU, how does C++ count it per thread? Does it simply broadcast same data if multiple threads query it at the same time? Or does it serialize operations in micro-operations behind to serve one thread at a time?

Above code compiles and gives this result(with `if(t1.joinable())` and `if(t2.joinable())`):

```
t1:  2  
t2:  3
```

does this mean thread 1 absolutely completed first or did it actually complete later but clock was requested for it first so that thread 2 got a lag?

Without checking if they are joinable:

```
t1:  1
t2:  1
```

Comment: Note that `t1` and `t2` are both joinable. There's no need to check that before joining them.

Comment: Because they are initialized and not joined before?

Comment: It would be much faster to look it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::chrono::system_clock` standard:

> 23.17.7.1 Class system_clock [time.clock.system]
>
> Objects of class system_clock represent wall clock time from the
>   system-wide realtime clock.

system-wide realtime clock, implies that all the processes retrieve the same time point. And the call should not cause a block.

Comment: Does system-wide mean that every core has its own counter with exactly same value with other cores all triggered on every clock cycle of a common clock generator(system-wide) at the same time?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik it should be OS/hardware dependent. I'm not aware of implementation detail. However it should be guaranteed that all the callers should retrieve the same time point.